# Xcode 8 AutoLayout/Constraints: Changing view to fit each Iphone screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am new to Xcode, and have been trying to figure out how to use AutoLayout and constraints. Long story short, after I hit 'add missing constraints' the Iphone 7 screen looks just as I intended, but both the Iphone 7 plus and Iphone SE screens look completely screwed up. What can I do to fix this so that every screen looks like the Iphone 7?

[Iphone 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA3xZ.png)

[Example Iphone SE (screwed up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvgUF.png)

Comment: You need to work through each item that is wrong and add the right constraints. There are no short cuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add missing constrains option means: adds the constraints needed to have a nonambiguous layout. may not work well for all iOS devices, and may not work well for device's rotation changes or view size changes, so, check view's constrains in size inspector panel

[image: check constrains in size inspector panel]

for more info:[check Apple's auto layout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.ahtml)